# Replace values in one column condition on another column: R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two columns and the data is jumbled between them. Both the columns are factors.
Example:

```
Skill       Employment
Skilled     A
Unskilled   B
12443       Skilled
24233       Skilled
```

I want the output:

```
Skill       Employment
Skilled     A
Unskilled   B
Skilled     (Don't care if its blank or has the original values)
Skilled     (Don't care if its blank or has the original values)
```

I have tried:

```
df %>% mutate(Skill = ifelse(Employment %in% c("Skilled", "Unskilled"), Skill, Employment))
```

I think I'm close but I don't know where I'm wrong.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Not an error. But a weird table with various counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl` to identify both `"Skilled"` and `"Unskilled"`. Change those values from `Employment` column to `Skill` column and make `Employment` column as `NA`.

```
inds <- grepl('Skill', df$Employment)
df$Skill[inds] <- df$Employment[inds]
df$Employment[inds] <- NA
df

#      Skill Employment
#1   Skilled          A
#2 Unskilled          B
#3   Skilled       <NA>
#4   Skilled       <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `case_when` after converting the `factor` columns to `character`

```
library(dplyr)
df <-  df %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character),
          Skill = case_when(
           Employment %in% c("Skilled", "Unskilled") ~ "Skilled",
             TRUE ~ Skill))
```

---

Or using an index in `base R`

```
i1 <- df$Employment %in% c("Skilled", "Unskilled")
df$Skill[i1] <- "Skilled"
```

Comment: I think you need to do something about the factor variable. I'm getting the following error:

x must be a character vector, not a `factor` object.
i Input `Skill` is `case_when(...)`.

Comment: @AmoghJoshi Updated the post.  I was thinking that the levels didn't change, so it should work.  May be `case_when` have some issues with that

Comment: Okay this works. The only thing I have to do is to convert everything back to factors. That's fine. The solution works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`which(df[,"Employment"] %in% c("Skilled","Unskilled")` will tell you which rows are wrong. You can then integrate that code into something that flips the columns in rows that are wrong. For example `df[which(df[,"Employment"] %in% c("Skilled","Unskilled")),"Skill"]<-df[which(df[,"Employment"] %in% c("Skilled","Unskilled")),"Employment"]` This example would only correct one column.

Correcting for the parenthesis - which keyword was not closed.

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm not sure what I did wrong. There was no change in the table. Got the same output.

Comment: I think it was due to the missing closing bracket. @AmoghJoshi, your edit should solve the problem. If it still doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: The code didn't compile until I fixed it in the Rstudio (which is how I know there was a problem. Thanks for answer! I'll see if it works.